# Exception while fetching data (/getAccidentsForDriver) : null" from a GraphQL query in Postman

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, graphql, hql

I'm using Spring MVC, with Hibernate and GraphQL.

I have 2 entity classes: `Driver` and `AccidentHistory`.

```
public class Driver implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int personId;
    private Set<AccidentHistory> accidentHistories = new HashSet<AccidentHistory>(0);
    //Rest of the class
```

```
public class AccidentHistory implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private Driver driver;
    //Rest of the class
```

I want to return all the `AccidentHistory` for an ID of a `Driver`, but I cannot get it to work for the life of me and all I get is the exception which tells me **close to nothing**.

This is the HQL:

```
"FROM AccidentHistory WHERE driver.personId = :id"
```

This is my GraphQL query:

```
query {
    getAccidentsForDriver(id: 1) {
            id
    }
}
```

Why does this exception happen?

Answer (score 0):

After running the same code on another computer, we figured out that the project on my laptop wasn't building for some weird ass reason. The query is correct and there were no problems in general.

I would just add that you need this line in your *.graphqls:

```
getAccidentsForDriver(id: Int!): [AccidentHistory]
```